# How can I solve 'vctrs' update problem running 'car' packages?

Tags: vctrs

> library(carData)
>   library(car)
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly says that it is required a version greater than `0.2.0` So please download the latest version which you can found here:- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vctrs/index.html